# Magento 1.9: Change Grid/List View Based on Category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, view

My default view is List view, how can I change based on category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it under custom design tab for the category you want to force the grid / list view by entering the following in the Custom Layout Update:

> Grid View:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setData">
        <key>_current_grid_mode</key> 
        <value>grid</value>
    </action>
</reference>
```

> List View:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setData">
        <key>_current_grid_mode</key>
        <value>list</value>
    </action>
</reference>
```

You can also do this with the help of this free [extension](https://github.com/btantlinger/DefaultCatView).

***Hope this helps!!!***